# Get text() Content by Click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, d3.js

Idea: Users could select a country in a World Map by clicking. And get text value.

Problem: After clicking, it shows but not the country:

```
*S.fn.init(176) [title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title, title,*
```

Please check line 39 --`$("g").click(function(){console.log($("title").text(this))});` Any solutions? Beginner needs help!

```js
const svg =d3.select("svg");

//d3.geoPath generates SVG path data string or renders the path to a canvas
//projection() 
const preProjection =d3.geoNaturalEarth1();
const pathDrawing = d3.geoPath().projection(preProjection);

const g = svg.append("g");

//draw sphere for squared map
g.append("path")
    .attr("class", "bgColor")
    .attr("d", pathDrawing({type: "Sphere"}));


//loading two files
Promise.all([
    d3.tsv("https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/110m.tsv"),
    d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/world-atlas@2/countries-110m.json")
]).then(([idData, countryData]) => {

    const countryName = {};
    idData.forEach(data =>{
        countryName[data.iso_n3] = data.name;
    });

    const drawCountry = topojson.feature(countryData, countryData.objects.countries);
    g.selectAll("path").data(drawCountry.features)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "drawCountry")
    .attr("d", pathDrawing)
    .append("title")
    //read countryName by id
    .text(
        d=>countryName[d.id]
    );
    //jQuery get()
    //$("g").click(function(){console.log($("title").text(d=>countryName[d.id]))});
    $("g").click(function(){console.log($("title").text(this))});
});

//d3.zoom() & panning
var zoom = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoomed);
function zoomed(){
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    };
var zoomElem = g.call(zoom);
//resetBtn
function resetBtn(){
    zoomElem.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
.bgColor {
    fill:darkblue;
}
.drawCountry{
    fill:lightgreen;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 0.01px;
}

.drawCountry:hover{
    fill: rgba(238, 17, 17, 0.699);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>NarrativeVis</head>
    <body>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="mapStyle.css">
        <script src = "https://unpkg.com/d3@5.6.0/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src = "https://unpkg.com/topojson@3.0.2/dist/topojson.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <svg width="959" height ="500"></svg>
        <script src = "map.js"></script>
        <input type = "button" value = "Reset" onclick='resetBtn()'/> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not sure what you expect `$("g").click(function(){console.log($("title").text(this))});` to do, but it temporarily breaks the browser

Comment: `function(e){console.log(e.target.__data__.properties.name)}` logs the country name if that helps

Comment: @Bravo Thanks, bro. This is what I was trying to get. I am a new coder. Could you please more about e.target.__data__.properties.name ? How to get this or how does it work?

Comment: I showed you how to get it, there it is ... how it works ... well, that's that `e.target` has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bravo said it before, the solution is to get the country name is the following:

> $("g").click(function(e){console.log(e.target.**data**.properties.name)});

But this method also works

```
console.log(e.target.textContent)
```

And you asked what exactly **e** is. It's a handler (event) which refers to the element you click on (in this case). Every single event has it's own functions. If you want to figure out that what kind of values it stores, just write this out in the console, like:

```
console.log(e.target)
```

This will show you that what kind of events/values you can use from the current context. You can use this method in any other fields if you want to know more about the default parameters.

For example, if you want to test it:

```
console.log(e.target.__data__)
```

it's also show you more details about your selection (like coordinates).

Comment: Appreciated for the details. Thanks Nagy.